# c random int types

Tags: c, random, types

i need to put some int into strings like here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
int alea1= rand()%11;
int alea2= rand()%11;

int add=alea1+alea2;
char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
printf(%s, question);
return 0;
}
```

I need to put this into a string because after that im using

```
if (cJSON_AddStringToObject(qr, "Question", question) == NULL){
  goto end;
}
```

but i get this:

```
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
                   ^~~~
test.c:11:37: error: conflicting types for ‘alea1’
  char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
                                     ^~~~~
test.c:7:6: note: previous definition of ‘alea1’ was here
  int alea1= rand()%11;
      ^~~~~
test.c:11:44: error: conflicting types for ‘alea2’
  char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
                                            ^~~~~
test.c:8:6: note: previous definition of ‘alea2’ was here
  int alea2= rand()%11;
      ^~~~~
test.c:12:9: error: expected expression before ‘%’ token
  printf(%s, question);
```

I tried strcat but i need to convert int to char dunno how to do this.
i tried var=fprint("str&var", ...);
but it is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You missed the header `<time.h>` which you need to declare the `time()` function.  You could pass NULL as the argument to `time()` which avoids the unused variable `t`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mean to use string formatting to a buffer.

```c
// char a[N] = "", x, y; is not valid c syntax
char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
printf(%s, question);
```

One way to do this is with `snprintf` which takes in a pointer to a sized buffer it can then write the string to.

```c
char question[250];
snprintf(question, sizeof question, "add %d to %d", alea1, alea2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What this line does:

```
char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
```

Is defined a `char` array named `question` initialized with a string constant, along with two additional `char` variables called `alea1` and `alea2`.  The latter two conflict with the `int` variables of the same name.

What you're looking for is `sprintf`, which does formatted printing and puts the result in a string instead of printing to stdout:

```
char question[256];
sprintf(question, "add %d to %d", alea1, alea2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not C:

```
char question[256]="add %d to %d", alea1, alea2;
printf(%s, question);
```

Probably you wanted to say something like:

```
printf("add %d to %d gives %d\n", alea1, alea2, alea1+alea2);
```

instead.